# return false - blocks all links on the page

Tags: jquery, cookies, prestashop

The problem is when search page is open all links are not active. So, i found the problem came form this JQUERY code:

```
var shouldShow = $.cookie('show_desc') == 'yep';
            if( shouldShow ) { $('#searchunder').show(); $('body').animate({ paddingTop: 80 }); }
            else {             $('#searchunder').hide(); $('body').animate({ paddingTop: 25 }); }

        // shows the group_desciption on clicking the noted link
        $('#search').click(function() {
            $('body').animate({ paddingTop: 80 });
            $('#searchunder').show('fast');
            $.cookie('show_desc', 'yep');
            return false;
        });
        // hides the group_desciption on clicking the noted link
        $('#close').click(function() {
            $('body').animate({ paddingTop: 25 });
            $('#searchunder').hide('fast');
            $.cookie('show_desc', 'nope');
            return false;
        });
```

If i add **//return false;** links are working. But if i remove *return false;* my search bar is hidding and then opens again. So what will be the solution?

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: What is the HTML structure?

Comment: In the fiddle it will work just fine... The problem is ony on prestashop search page, since it is using AJAX and other JS codes. so this some how gets in CONFLICT. However if remove RETURN FALSE, it wirk just fine except the hide and show function.

Comment: @AndrewS: That doesn't mean it's not possible to create a [minimal, self-contained example](http://sscce.org). Just that it may be more work.

Answer (score 1):

In a jQuery handler, `return false` does two things: Stops propagation and prevents the default action.

The only way the code you've shown could prevent links from being followed would be if they were *within* the `#search` and/or `#close` elements. If that's the problem, you can solve it like this:

```
$('#search').click(function() {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('a')[0]) { // Check if click was on `a` element
        $('body').animate({ paddingTop: 80 });
        $('#searchunder').show('fast');
        $.cookie('show_desc', 'yep');
        return false;
    }
});
```

(And similarly for `#close`.)

...which only runs the relevant code if the click wasn't on an `a` element.

Note: The above assumes that `#search` and `#close` are not, themselves, `a` elements and that they aren't *within* `a` elements. E.g., they contain links, but are not links nor contained *by* links. That can be solved too, it just requires a tiny bit more code: Instead of

```
if (!$(e.target).closest('a')[0]) { // Check if click was on `a` element
```

it would be

```
if (!$(e.target).parentsUntil(this).filter('a')[0]) { // Check if click went through an `a` element en route to us
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well there is some + but also a -. After addign this  if (!$(e.target).closest('a')[0]) {. the event click is not working. not open and not close! However links on the page are active now. So, why the function event is not working?

Comment: @AndrewS: Did you see the bit at the end? That might be it... If not, it'll be something similar. Fundamentally, you just want to make sure that you're not processing a click that bubbles up to these elements if that click passed through a link, but you *do* want to otherwise. :-)